# What is the difference between DLL and SLL implementations?

Tags: data-structures, stl, linked-list, stack, containers

What is the difference between DLL(double linked list ) and SLL (single linked list)
implementations?

Comment: one has only one pointer to the next item, the other has another for pointing to the previous item

Answer (score 1):

**DOUBLY LINKED LIST**
DLL has both a previous and a next pointer. Hence any node of the linked list contains address of both the previous and the next node.
This is very useful when you need to traverse both ways in a linked list and deletion of specific nodes.

**SINGLE LINKED LIST**
SLL only has a next pointer. Hence a node can reference only the next node in the linked list.
SLL is simpler in terms of implementation, and typically has a smaller memory requirement as it only needs to keep the forward member referencing in place.

[image: PICTORIAL REPRESENTATION OF cIRCULAR SLL AND DLL]